# Facebook Graph API - Retrieving friends belonging to specific list

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am quite sure it is supposed to work but can't get it right.
I am trying to retrieve my friends belonging to specific list (type=close_friends).
I am able to retrieve my lists via 
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friendlists
But i need the actual friends associated with each list.
I would expect it to be something like:
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FriendList](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/FriendList/) is a Graph API object supporting a `members` connection.

Comment: Tnx, although it will required at least two requests (one to get the lists and one to retrieve the members). I think I am going to use FQL, something like: `SELECT uid FROM friendlist_member WHERE flid IN (SELECT flid FROM friendlist WHERE owner=me() AND type="close_friends")`